# Miniconda KeyError: 'path' when trying to activate any conda environment

Tags: python, miniconda

So, I first got this error when trying to install the oobabooga/text-generation-webui. I realized the error had to do with the installation of miniconda, so I tried installing it separately to see if it worked. The `conda` command itself worked, so I tried creating an environment, and then tried to activate it. Got the same error. Here's the full error:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:\Users\david\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 16, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "F:\Users\david\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 111, in main_sourced
        print(activator.execute(), end="")
      File "F:\Users\david\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 189, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "F:\Users\david\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 155, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "F:\Users\david\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 333, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "F:\Users\david\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 362, in _build_activate_stack
        conda_prompt_modifier = self._prompt_modifier(prefix, conda_default_env)
      File "F:\Users\david\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 724, in _prompt_modifier
        return context.env_prompt.format(
    KeyError: 'path'

`$ F:\Users\david\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py shell.cmd.exe activate hello`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=F:\Users\david\miniconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="F:\Users\david\miniconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
               CONDA_ROOT=F:\Users\david\miniconda3
                CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\david
               LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
                     PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU
                          Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\Eclipse
                          Adoptium\jdk-8.0.345.1-hotspot\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\PlasticSCM5\server;C:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\client;C:\Window
                          s\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Win
                          dowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
                          Files\dotnet\;F:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\eSpeak\command_line;
                          C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Prog
                          ram Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\david\zlib123dllx64\dll_x64;C:\Program
                          Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute
                          2022.3.0\;C:\ffmpeg\bin;F:\Program Files\AutoFirma\AutoFirma;F:\Users\
                          david\miniconda3;F:\Users\david\miniconda3\Library\mingw-
                          w64\bin;F:\Users\david\miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;F:\Users\david\minic
                          onda3\Library\bin;F:\Users\david\miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\david\App
                          Data\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\david\AppData\L
                          ocal\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft
                          \WindowsApps;E:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\b
                          in;C:\Users\david\.dotnet\tools;C:\SqLite3;C:\Users\david\AppData\Roam
                          ing\npm;C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;F:\Users\david\
                          miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=F:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\david\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\david\.condarc
          conda version : 23.5.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.11.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __cuda=12.2=0
                          __win=0=0
       base environment : F:\Users\david\miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : F:\Users\david\miniconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : F:\Users\david\miniconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\david\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : F:\Users\david\miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\david\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/23.5.0 requests/2.29.0 CPython/3.10.11 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19045
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

The configuration file (.condarc) looks like this:

```
channels:
  - defaults
env_prompt: "'({name})\\n{path}'"
```

And this is the environments.txt file:

```
F:\Users\david\miniconda3
F:\Users\david\miniconda3\envs\test
F:\Users\david\miniconda3\envs\hello
```

I've tried uninstalling miniconda and re-installing it in different directories. I tried creating multiple different environments, but again, same error when trying to activate them.